# Is there a way to expand all subfolders of a specific folder in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Suppose I have a folder structure as below.
I'd like to expand all subfolders recursively only for JavaTest1 folder.
If I click Expand All icon, it expands all other folders JavaTest2,3,4 recursively as well, but I don't want to expand JavaTest2,3,4 recursively.
Is there a way to expand all subfolder recursively for a specific folder in IntelliJ?

[image]

Answer (score 6):

The action is called **Fully Expand Tree Node**. You can check the shortcuts for your keymap or assign a new shortcut in the IDE Settings:

[image: Fully expand tree node]